# How to create python regex to match only if at least 3 defined words are exist and allow other random words as well?

Tags: python, regex, string, slack

Here is my example:

```
re.compile("({tables}) ({middle})  ({end})"format(tables=config.kvkk_tables,middle=config.middle_sentence,end=config.end_of_sentence),re.IGNORECASE))
```

One of tables, middle and end string must be in sentence. When this condition matched we do not want to check any other things allow any random words and characters.

```
tables = "oms.claim|oms.order"

middle = "request|requested"

end = "respond|responded|answer|answered"
```

First Example:(Example needs to be matched) since there are at least 1 word from **tables**, **middle** and **end**.

> "Hello could you please define my username for oms.claim table as it
> is requested by order department and needs to be answered
> immediately."

Second Example:(Example needs to be NOT matched) since there are not any word from **end** string.

> "Hi, oms.order table requested from me, could you please help me about
> that?"

What I tried and failed:

```
@bolt_app.message(re.compile("({tables}) ({middle} |(:?) {end})".
                         format(tables=config.kvkk_tables,middle=config.middle_sentence,end=config.end_of_sentence),re.IGNORECASE))
```

Comment: It's possible with anchored lookaheads, but not sure that regex is the best solution for that. (not very scalable). Why you don't try to tokenize the string and to use sets intersections?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, I tried using boundry but still did not work: 
  re.compile(r"\b{tables}\b \b{middle}\b \b{end}\b".format(tables,middle,end))

Comment: Problem about above one is, it is matches if one of the 3 word groups are matches. But it is required to have words from 3 groups and random characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out.

```
re.compile("{tables}.* {middles}.* {end}".format(tables=config.kvkk_tables, middles=config.middles, end=config.end_of_sentence),re.IGNORECASE)
```

So key point was using `.*`

[This site](https://pythex.org/) is helped me a lot to test python regex

Note: I also covered my string definition in config.py with paranthesis like below:

```
tables = "(oms.claim|oms.order)"

middle = "(request|requested)"

end = "(respond|responded|answer|answered)"
```